# play raw PCM wave audio in Win8 (consumer preview)

Tags: audio, windows-8

Is it possible to stream or play raw uncompressed PCM audio data in Windows 8? I don't want to play a file, but rather push my own audio samples (e.g. generate a sine wave). I'm running the Win8 consumer preview. I know that NAudio can do this in Win7 and earlier editions of Windows. I've tried referencing NAudio in a Visual Studio 11 project but NAudio has a dependency on System.Windows.Forms.dll, which does not exist (as far as I can tell) on the Win8 consumer preview. Is there another way to accomplish this in the Win8 preview? I'd prefer a solution using managed code or JavaScript.

Comment: I was able to find the System.Windows.Forms.dll assembly, but Visual Studio 11 crashes whenever I add the reference.

Comment: I also see that there is a SetSource method on a MediaElement. Maybe that could work? It accepts an IRandomAccessStream...  any thoughts on what that stream should contain would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't specify language of your chice, so I am going to assume C#. For C# I can think of couple possible options:

1. SharpDX + XAudio2. This would work for C++ as well without the need for SharpDX
2. In Silverlight you can use MediaStreamSource - [Playing back Wave files in Silverlight](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/gillesk/archive/2009/03/23/playing-back-wave-files-in-silverlight.aspx). I don't see it in WinRT, but similar alternative might exist.
3. Write winrt library in C++ utilizing XAudio2. This way you wouldn't need to use SharpDX and you can call it from C# or JavaScript app.

Comment: A managed code solution is best (I modified my question to be more specific). SharpDX looks promising. I'm very familiar with playing uncompressed WAV data using a MediaStreamSource in Silverlight, but that buffer-based approach has too much latency for my needs. I'll give SharpDX a shot.